# Composing with a biholomorphic function does not affect the order of pole

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Let $f$ be a meromorphic function on a Riemann surface $X$, and let
>   $f(p)=\infty$. Show that for any chart $(U_{\alpha},\phi_{\alpha})$ with $p\in U_{\alpha}$ the function $f\circ \phi_{\alpha}^{-1}$ is meromorphic in $\phi_{\alpha} (U_{\alpha})$ and has a pole at $\phi_{\alpha}(p)$.
>
> Furthermore, the order of this pole is independent of the chart and the residue is not necessarily independent of the chart.

Now I am working on the second part. Here is my attempt:

Pick up another chart $(\tilde{U}_{\alpha},\tilde{\phi}_{\alpha})$, then 
$$f\circ \tilde{\phi}_{\alpha}^{-1}=f\circ \phi_{\alpha}^{-1}\circ \phi_{\alpha}\circ \tilde{\phi}_{\alpha}^{-1}=(f\circ \phi_{\alpha}^{-1})\circ( \phi_{\alpha}\circ \tilde{\phi}_{\alpha}^{-1})$$
So it is enough to prove the following result:

For a biholomorphic function $h$ and a meromorphic function $g$, we have 
$$\mathrm{ord}_p g=\mathrm{ord}_p (g\circ h).$$

Suppose 
$$g(z)=\frac{a(z)}{(z-p)^k}$$
for some holomorphic function $a(z)$. Then
$$g(h(z))=\frac{a(h(z))}{((z-p)+o(z-p)-p)^k}=\frac{1}{(z-p)^k}h'$$
for some holomorphic function $h'$.

Comment: Just expand $g$ and $h$ around the pole. You should get that $h$'s starts $(x-a)+o(x-a)$. Then use the definition of order. Namely, the smallest $n$ such that $(x-a)^{n+1}f(x)$ converges to zero when $x\to a$.

Comment: @orole Thanks a lot!

Comment: Wait wait, no so fast. It is my fault for using the same name in both cases. But you look at which point to expand each function. If $g$ has a pole at $p$ and $h$ maps $a$ to $p$ Then you need to expand $h$ at $a$. The expansion of $h$ is then $p+(z-a)+o(z-a)$.

Comment: @orole I see! Thanks again!